# What is the difference between 残念ながら and 残念なことに

Tags: word-choice, grammar, usage

I hear both 残念ながら and 残念なことに when expressing that something was unfortunate before the actual sentence, much like the English "Unfortunately, ...".

However, I'm not sure on where these two phrases differ. Is their usage the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the difference is:

In `残念ながら` the focus is on the speaker's feeling while they tell you the information. It's like saying "I'm sorry to have to tell you, but..." The speaker's feeling of disappointment exists *alongside* the information.

In `残念なことに`, the focus is on the thing the speaker is telling you, and is a cause of the disappointment. It's like saying "What's particularly disappointing is..." The speaker's disappointment *comes from* the information.

> 残念ながら、あなたと別れる。　(It's sad, but I'm going to break up with you.)
>
> 残念なことに、結婚しようかなと思っていた。　(What's sad is, I thought we maybe could have
>   married.)

These two examples are subtley different. In the in the first case, you are being told that a breakup will happen, *despite* the fact the speaker is sad about it. In the second case, you are being given a fact which is *itself* a cause of disappointment.

Hope that helps.

Comment: 「あなたと仲違いしている」sounds wrong to me.  I feel like 「縁を切る／断つ／絶つ」or 「別れる」would be better.

Comment: 別れる is by far the most normal. I just came across the word 仲違い recently and thought I'd run it up the flagpole and see if anyone salutes. I may edit it out if it's considered too out there.

Comment: 別れている does not mean "am breaking up with you", it means "have broken up with you". ている for change-of-state verbs expresses then completed state.

Comment: @dainichi: I've edited to hopefully correct it. Better?

Comment: https://m.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/detail/q14161438229 and http://nihon5ch.net/contents/bbs-study/old/mie-bbs.cgi?s=118 seem to indicate that the difference is actually the opposite of what you said, with 残念なことに focusing on the feeling, and 残念ながら focusing on the information/result. So what's the real answer?

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Dave that the two seem very close.  If we look at the core definitions, we can see this:

#### 〜ながら: "while 〜"

Although we usually stick this on the end of the verb stem (食べながら、見ながら、など), it can retain the same meaning in English here.

- 残念ながら、...　→  "While it's unfortunate, (here's the truth of it) ..."

#### (emotion/feeling word) + ことに(は): "Very 〜", "To my 〜"

- おどろいたことに　→　"To my surprise" / "Surprisingly"
- 嬉しいことに　→　"Very happily"
- 残念なことに　→　"Very unfortunately" / "To my disappointment"

Answer (score 3):

To me, the two are nigh identical. With `残念ながら` *ever so slightly* less formal-sounding (and more common) than `残念なことに`...

According to [this site](http://nihon5ch.net/contents/bbs-study/old/mie-bbs.cgi?s=118):

> たまたまこの文の場合は、文頭に来る「～ことに」と逆接になる「～ながら」の「～」のところに「残念」という言葉が来ているので、似た用法となっていますね。

Which I roughly interpret as 「〜ことに」giving more surprise/contradiction (but I must admit I'm not all that clear and could be wholly mistranslating that one... anybody care to confirm/infirm?).

At any rate, grammar is slightly different:

- 残念**なことに**、抜かなければならない歯は、このような歯です。
- 残念**ながら**　　抜くことになる歯は　　　　このような歯です。